# What is the expected runtime range of pragma quick_check?

Tags: sqlite

I'm going to run `PRAGMA quick_check` on a very large SQLite database and would like to estimate the time it will take to complete. Is there a (ballpark) way to do that, assuming a reasonably fast HDD or SSD? Is it O(n) or worse?

I'm obviously not looking for an accurate prediction, just something like "1 to 5 hours per 10 GB".

Comment: That depends on factors (memory, I/O) that you did not specify. Anyway, you have to measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick_check checks for out-of-order records, missing pages, malformed records, and CHECK, and NOT NULL constraint errors.

It can be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended as an answer, but as a reference point, until someone more knowledgeable than I am can help out with a more general answer.

A 90GB sqlite3 database (1 table, 1 index, 20m rows) took 13 hours on my mid grade SSD with 16 GB RAM, running Windows7/NTFS. The process was clearly disk bound.

Assuming a linear dependency, this comes out as **5-10 minutes per Gigabyte**.

According to a few pages I found online, a full `PRAGMA check_integrity` takes roughly 8 times longer (1h/GB).